# PHP - deny visitor access to 2.php if they have not visited 1.php in the last x seconds

Tags: php, html

I know I'm supposed to include "some knowledge" on this but I'm honestly extremely stuck on it. I don't even know where to start.

To stop `spamming`, I can put a `Google Captcha` on my `index.php` I know, but users can simply visit `example.com/code_execute.php` and a blank paste page still gets created.

I need it so that if a user goes to `code_execute.php` has not visited `index.php` in x amount of seconds (defined in a variable perhaps?) they are just redirected back to the index.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this? I'm new to PHP and only know a bit of simple HTML and CSS. Enough to get a site working though.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Set a session variable on index.php when they complete the captcha and verify the session variables on code_execute.php

Comment: Hmm can you give me a small example? or elaborate? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a session variable on index.php when they complete the captcha and verify the session variables on code_execute.php

An example would be like this

index.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['some_key'] = true;
$_SESSION['when'] = time();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
    <center>
        <h3>Thank you for visiting us!!!</h3>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <a href="code_exec.php">Go to next page</a>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

code_exec.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['some_key'], $_SESSION['when']) 
|| ((time() - $_SESSION['when']) > 60)) { //redirect if more than 60 seconds have passed

    header('location:index.php');
    die();

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code Exec</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Code Exec Page</h1>
        <h3>Thank you for participating</h3>
        <h5>Now go away...</h5>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This example sets the session variable on the get request which is not what you may want. As soon as they request `index.php` the timer starts counting.
You should set the session variable after they submit the captcha
and use more than 60 seconds otherwise it may get annoying for users

Comment: --update-- IT works! Thank you so much Josh. I really really appreciate that.

Comment: I had to actually incluce 
}
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

after the Die part for it to work entirely. :D

Answer (score 2):

1. you can use session variables. `session_cache_expire(5);session_start(); session['set'] = 'something';`
2. You can use default `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check the visits origin url for the page.
3. You mentioned about allowing user if he visit the 2.php after certain time, you can do this by setting the session to some time when they visit 1.php and then you can check time they visit 2.php using `$maxlifetime = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");`

**Edit:**
**Example:**
in **2.php**

```
<?php
// This is to check if the request is coming from a specific URL
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if($ref !== 'http://example.com/1.php') {
  header('Location: 1.php');
   //Alternates as necessary
  // header('Location: /directory/1.php');
 //header('Location: http://example.com/1.php');
  exit;
}

//Your code if from 1.php
?>
```

Comment: Hmm this is still really new to me so I'm having trouble understanding it. How would I put on 2.php something like (mind my horrible formatting)

Comment: if $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = example.com/index.php do nothing. otherwise go back to index.php